Additional type of entering to holding pattern
Does anyone know any other types of entering to holding pattern besides the standard ones?
I’m trying to become a cpt and our local comission asked this question to me. They said that there is an addition 4’th type. But I know only three.

This depends on local fight rules.  ICAO allows a "Secondary Fix" entry, which is similar to an offset/teardrop entry, except the instruction is to fly to the secondary fix first, rather than the holding fix first.
FAA allows for "other entry procedures" that are not among the three recommended entries.  Keep in mind, ATC does not always issue holding instructions in combination with a direct course to a holding fix.  An aircraft on a non-radial heading away from a fix in space could be instructed to "turn right and hold" at such fix.  Depending on the present position, heading, speed, turn radius, published hold or airway, and navigation equipment, the pilot would have to design an entry appropriate for that scenario.
References:
Conventional Holding (ICAO)
AIM 5-3-8 (FAA)
